# Ubuntu not booting, hanging before terminal is accessible

Tags: boot, command-line, shutdown, reboot

I had a power outage last night. My pc is running Ubuntu 20.04. It’s on a UPS and I was able to shut down the pc, and when it was shut down, I turned the UPS off.

Today the power was restored, and I’ve tried booting the pc and it won’t boot to the screen I’m used to seeing (GUI).

After pushing the power button, after the bios splash, there is usually a black screen that displays “[ 0.213986 x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.” - etcetera. There is usually 10-14 lines of outputs that say some things like “CIFS: VFS:” but at most it takes a minute to get to the end of that task and will then boot into the GUI. It seems to be hung here.

If I try typing, like “sudo” and push enter, nothing happens. If I type Ctrl+C it outputs ^C. I assume terminal hasn’t launched yet, so I can’t do anything. However, if I go to my iPad I can watch Plex, open Radarr/Sonarr etc.

I know some things, but I don’t know how to recover this.

Comment: If the machine wasn't cleanly shutdown (*prior to power loss*), I'd boot a *live* system and perform file-systems checks, and if any errors are detected & fixed, I'd expect normal operation when you next boot normally.  Otherwise I'd switch to a text terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F4 for example) & login & explore the system logs to look for clues (explore `dmesg` or `journalctl` etc).

Comment: The computer was cleanly shut down. “ It’s on a UPS and I was able to shut down the pc, and when it was shut down, I turned the UPS off.”

Thank you for the command to load into text terminal. What does explore mean? Where is dmesg or journalctl located? Nano dmesg opens a blank screen, and ls shows the folders and files located in /home/Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Hold shift on boot to display the GRUB, and select “Advanced options for Ubuntu”. You will be presented with a list of Kernels. The top will be the default option, and if selecting (recovery mode) still doesn’t allow the system to boot, try booting the previous kernel, typically the third option down. If the system boots without issue, then try removing the problematic kernel.

Eg: "Linux 5.15.0-94-generic"

- Boot into Ubuntu by selecting "Linux 5.15.0-92-generic" and open a terminal window.
- Identify the currently running kernel version by running the command:  uname -r
- This will display the kernel version you are currently using. Make sure not to remove this version.
- List all installed kernels using the command:  dpkg --list | grep linux-image
- This will list all installed kernel images along with their versions.
- Identify the kernel version "Linux 5.15.0-94-generic" from the list.
- To remove the kernel, use the command:  sudo apt --purge remove linux-image-5.15.0-94-generic
- This will remove the problematic kernel image.
- Additionally, you might want to remove the corresponding headers and module packages for 5.15.0-94 too.
- List the related packages with the command: dpkg --list | grep 5.15.0-94
- And finally remove all listed packages related to the kernel by repeating the command: sudo apt --purge remove “kernel”
- After removing the problematic kernel and its headers, reboot your system to ensure everything is working correctly with the remaining kernels.